# How to store a file in DB with pyramid and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a Pyramid web application and I need to store uploaded files to a postgresql DB with SQLAlchemy. I already got access to the file through an AJAX call with a `FormData` object and saved in a variable, but I can't store it to the SQLAlchemy model.

I've tried with something like `ControlFile.content = file_object.file`, but I get the following error: **can't escape _io.BytesIO to binary**

Here are my code snippets

#### DB

```
CREATE TABLE "control_file"(
--  ...
    "content" bytea NOT NULL
--  ...
);
```

#### SQLAlchemy

```
class ControlFile(BaseStatusAll):
    __tablename__ = 'control_file'
    content = Column(LargeBinary)
    #...
```

## Pyramid

```
@view_config(route_name='add_file_to_control', renderer='json', request_method='POST')
def add_file(request):
    file_object = request.params.get('file')
    cf = ControlFile()
    cf.content = file_object.file
    # SQLAlchemy session
    request.dbsession.add(cf)
    #...
    return {'status': 1}
```

## JS

Here's the script I use to upload the file. Note that `file` is a `File` object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", file);
$.ajax({
    'url': '...',
    'method':'POST',
    'async': false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fd
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround, but I'm sure there have to be a better way to do this.

So, in general, what I do is

1. Access the object's file property, where the bytes string resides
2. Create a temporal file using `shutil` and the bytes string
3. Read the temporal file and set its content to the SQLAlchemy model's property
4. Save the object
5. Delete the temporal file

```
import shutil
# 1
cf = ControlFile()
request_file = file_object.file

# 2
with open('temp/' + file_object.filename, 'wb') as output_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(request_file, output_file)

# 3
with open('temp/' + file_object.filename, 'rb') as file:
    cf.content = file.read()

# 4
# SQLAlchemy session
request.dbsession.add(cf)

# 5
os.remove('temp/' + file_object.filename)
```

Comment: This should work? It should be possible to call read() directly on the file_object.file object?


`cf = ControlFile()`
`cf.content = file_object .file.read()`
`request.dbsession.add(cf)`